# What causes 'Constant captured by a closure before being initialized' error

Tags: swift, swift2

In a following class

```
class Foo {
   let _defaultValue = "N/A"
   let value: String 

   init (dict: NSDictionary) {
       self.value = dict["bar"] as? String! ?? _defaultValue
   }
}
```

compiler fails with the message
`constant 'self.value' captured by a closure before being initialized`

As far as I can see, no operators read `self.value. The message seems somewhat confusing.

I accidentally came up with a workaround. I should say it confuses me even more:

```
class Foo {
       let value: String 

       init (dict: NSDictionary) {
           let _defaultValue = "N/A"
           self.value = dict["bar"] as? String! ?? _defaultValue
       }
    }
```

Declaring `_defaultValue` and initializing it within the constructor makes the code compile.

It'd be an immense help if someone could explain why an error occurs in the first case and what is the compiler happier in the second case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that the nil-coalescing operator
is defined as

```
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T) rethrows -> T
```

and does a "auto closure" on the second argument (in order to get 
a short-circuiting behaviour). So

```
self.value = dict["bar"] as? String ?? _defaultValue
```

is transformed by the compiler to

```
self.value = dict["bar"] as? String ?? { self._defaultValue }()
```

and here the compiler complains because `self` is captured before
being fully initialised. (The error messages are slightly different
between Swift 2 and Swift 3).

*Possible workarounds.* You can assign the property to a local variable first:

```
init(dict: NSDictionary){
    let defValue = _defaultValue
    self.value = dict["bar"] as? String! ?? defValue
}
```

Or you can make it a static property of the class:

```
class Foo {
    static let _defaultValue = "N/A"
    let value: String

    init(dict: NSDictionary) {
        self.value = dict["bar"] as? String ?? Foo._defaultValue
    }
}
```

Or replace `??` by an if-statement:

```
class Foo {
    let _defaultValue = "N/A"
    let value: String

    init (dict: NSDictionary) {
        if let value = dict["bar"] as? String {
            self.value = value
        } else {
            self.value = _defaultValue
        }
    }
}
```

*Addendum:* Related resources:

- [Autoclosure of self in initializers](https://forums.swift.org/t/autoclosure-of-self-in-initializers/13651) in the Swift forum.
- [SR-944 Cannot use 'self' in RHS of && before all properties are initialized](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-944) bug report.

Quote from the bug report:

> Jordan Rose: This is true since && is implemented using @autoclosure, but it's certainly suboptimal.